# strange dock icon

Tags: macos, mac, dock, icon

Recently I noticed that a strange dock icon sometimes appears in the dock, somewhere near the Downloads folder. The icon will only appear for about 1 second and then it will disappear, so I am not fast enough to capture the screen.

Last time I saw that, I opened the Console and found that it might be somewhat related to my Avira Free Antivirus auto-update (and Avira was updating at that time). Still I'm not really sure what the icon is. Does anyone (especially Avira users) have any ideas on what the icon actually is? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am currently using OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

Comment: By any chance: https://sparkle-project.org ?

Comment: You could video it as a way of capturing it.